# Blackberry App for only OS 5.0+?

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know if you can specify which OS your app supports when submitting an app to Blackberry App World? I'm writing a jQuery Mobile + PhoneGap app, and jQuery Mobile doesn't render well in Blackberry 4.6, 4.7, etc., so I'd like to specify that the app is only supported in BB OS 5.0 & 6.0.

Answer (score 2):

a part of the [App World FAQ](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/appworld/faq.jsp):

> What do I need to submit an application?
>
> You’ll need to provide
>   the following information when
>   submitting an application:
>
> ```
> * Application name
> * Category
> * Application language
> * Description language
> * Description
> * Icon (480x480 png image)
> * Screenshots
> * License type
> * Price
> * COD files
> * Filebundle language
> * COD file language
> * Devices supported
> * OS version supported <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
> * Selected carriers
> * Restricted carriers
> * Additional notes
> * Application version
> ```

So I think there is such a possibility.

Comment: Thanks Arhimed - I saw this before I posed the question here. I'm wondering what this specifically means. Could mean 1) App is not displayed for devices running OS's you don't specify, 2) App is displayed for non-supported devices, with a warning message, or 3) other. 

I'm interested in how RIM handles the specification of "OS version supported" for submitted apps.

Comment: I really don't know the details on this. However there is a try-and-cut way to check that. For instance, take a look at this free app - http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/205?lang=en - it supports Bold 9000 and OS 5+. So it is possible to install 2 simulators of Bold 9000 (4.6 and 5.0) to point each of them to that app and watch what happens.